# disable field on rules model yii

Tags: yii

i am trying to disable a field on update rules models but i am having error.

i try like:

```
array('date', 'constraint', 'readOnly'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

but i am having this error:

"include(constraint.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

I can disable from view using htmloptions but i need do it from model because on update i need to disable more than 5 fields.

how could i do this?

thx in advance

Comment: That error is because the `Constraint` validator cannot be found. Instead of disabling the fields you could use plain text to display the values and hidden fields if the values are required for the next step.

Comment: I need to disable them for avoid modifications but i need to let them visible.

Comment: I think 'constraint' validation here may have come from reading http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4570-set-some-active-record-as-read-only/page__view__findpost__p__24179. That post goes on to say you need to create one. I haven't managed to get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring a rule with a validator that doesn't exist, so it's normal that you have an error:

```
array('date', 'constraint', 'readOnly'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

This line is doing the following: apply the validator `constraint` on the `date` field on `update` scenario with param `readOnly` set to `true`.

The validator `constraint` doesn't exists has a built in functonnality in Yii so if you havn't created it then it doesn't exist!

Documentation:

- [Validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules)
- [Model Rules validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/)

**Edit:** In your form you could do something like:

```
<?php 
    echo $form->textField(
        $model,
        'email',
        array('readonly'=>($model->scenario == 'update')? true : false)
    );
?>
```

As you can see the readonly value will depend on the scenario.

Comment: yes, you are right. I am using array('readonly'=>true) on _form but exist another form more elegant?

Comment: hum I think what you are doing is fine. See my edit for a solution!

Comment: i was defined 
`<?php if ($model->isNewRecord) { ...`
but your solution is better. Thx a lot